# HowTo enforce Play framework 2.4.x to serialize field with empty list

Tags: json, playframework-2.4, play-json

I'm using scala play! 2.4.x and trying to searialize case class:

```
case class MyEvent(
    id: String,
    parentId: Option[ParentRef] = None,
    stepStatus: String = "undefined",
    artifacts:Seq[String] = Seq.empty,
    events:Seq[String] = Seq.empty  
  )
```

The problem is that serialized json doesn't contain fields  **artifacts** and **events** since their default values are empty sequences. Receiver expects to get field names even if they are empty. 
I have to force json serializer to add **"artifacts": [], "events":[]**

What is the right way to do it without writing whole formatter manually? I have dozens fields.

Comment: Could you make the `artifacts` and `events` members `Option[Seq[String]]`? AFAIK no other way that doesn't involve write the `Reads/Format` manually.

Comment: You mean on receiver side? No, it's impossible.

Comment: When trying to reproduce this, I seem to pick up some differences in behaviour between 2.3 and 2.4. Couldn't resolve yet. In 2.3 artifacts and events are most definitely present and several SO questions are about trying to suppress them. No help I know. Let us know if you resolve.

Answer (score 0):

So, for 2.4.x it works this way:

```
case class MyEvent(
    id: String,
    parentId: Option[ParentRef] = None,
    stepStatus: String = "undefined",
    artifacts:Seq[String] = Seq(),
    events:Seq[String] = Seq()  
  )
```

**Seq()** forces play json to generate **"events": []** which is fine for me. I find play-json stuff a bit over engineered. :( I really miss google Gson from my Java past :) Dead simple and just works.